# noClassdefFoundError ExplodingSupplier

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I'm trying to run code for Selenium RC whith Selenium Webdriver in iexplore through WebDriverBackedSelenium.

in the SeleniumConfig.class I have:

```
  File file = new File("C:/Selenium/IEDriverServer.exe");
   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
   WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
   selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "https:// my web ");
```

Normally the code in SeleniumConfig for RC is

```
   selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", getPuerto(),
                    "*iexplore", "https:// my web");
   selenium.start();
```

and this works. But replacing with the new code I obtain this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/ExplodingSupplier
    at org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverCommandProcessor.<init>(WebDriverCommandProcessor.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.<init>(WebDriverBackedSelenium.java:30)
    at config.SeleniumConfig.start(SeleniumConfig.java:40)
    at idenLocaJava.LocaJavaSuite.setUp(LocaJavaSuite.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at   .....
```

And in the console:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.45.0.0
Listening on port 12628
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Some suggestions? May be I need some dependency in POM.XML?
I have:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
        </dependency>  
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>16.0.1</version>
         </dependency>
```

I need use java 7 and the latest compatible version is selenium 2.46.0 that also I tried.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your project is still referencing old selenium jars. Can you run "mvn dependency:tree" in your project and see if you are getting the correct versions. try cleaning and rebuilding.

The selemium classes in the error message (WebDriverCommandProcessor, and WebDriverBackedSelenium) are from old selenium packages. In 2.45.0 the should be:

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.WebDriverBackedSelenium
com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.WebDriverCommandProcessor
```

Comment: Oh, I changed **org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium** by **com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.WebDriverBackedSelenium** and it works! Thank you Mustafa!

Comment: great! glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting this issue generally because of jars or conflicts between different versions of jars. As here Maven is using good to provide required dependencies only may be selenium-java and selenium-server and off course one for htmlunit. More information is provided [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp)

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I added

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
         <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>   

    because without this I had
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/HasInputDevices

and 

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>16.0.1</version>
 </dependency>

becase whitout this i had

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/net/MediaType


I could delete 

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

But still the error
```